# Plotly yaxis cutoff

Tags: javascript, plotly

Trying to understand why my yaxis plot is cutoff. I can't figure out how to make the plot area to fit into the correct place.

Played with margins , but that's for the whole graph.

The code below.

```
    var layout = {
        showlegend: true,
        autoresize: false,
        width: document.getElementById(div_id).clientWidth,
        height: 371,
        margin: {
         l: 50,
         r: 50,
         b: 100,
         t: 100,
         pad: 0,
        },
        title: title,
        xaxis: {
            fixedrange: true,
            rangeselector: selectorOptions,
            rangeslider: {},
            type: 'date',
            title: 'Time',
        },
        yaxis: {
            automargin: true,
            fixedrange: true,
            autotick: true,
            autorange: true,
            tickformat: ".3s",
            title: 'Mbps'
        }
    };
```

The html div:

```
            <div class="x_content">
              <div id='{{item['index']}}div_id'"style="height:450px;"></div>
            </div>
```

[image: issue in red]

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is here:

```
 <div class="x_content">
          <div id='{{item['index']}}div_id'"style="height:450px;"></div>
        </div>
```

you set it to "height: 450px" so i guess you reached the maximum height, try it maybe with 600px

Comment: hi. I have height: 371, in the plotly , so this should no be a problem. I've changed it in the div but no luck.

Comment: Ok. so once i have move that 3 datapoints , it works. Strange , will raise it with plotly team

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with missing datapoints. Once i've added more datapoints to the plot , all is fine.